# Вывести результат события VK Bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vk-mini-apps

Создаю мини-приложение на основе библиотеки @vkontakte/create-vk-mini-app (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vkontakte/create-vk-mini-app).
Пытаюсь вывести VKWebAppGetClientVersion -- номер версии приложения в консоль
https://dev.vk.com/bridge/VKWebAppGetClientVersion
С таким кодом не выведется ничего. Пока учу язык, подскажите в какую сторону копать

```
const Br = () => {
    return(
        console.log(bridge.send("VKWebAppGetClientVersion"))
    );
}
```

Comment: А что выводит `console.log(bridge)` ?

Comment: @EzioMercer


{send: ƒ, sendPromise: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ, unsubscribe: ƒ, supports: ƒ, …}
isEmbedded: ƒ u()
isIframe: ƒ l()
isStandalone: ƒ ()
isWebView: ƒ i()
send: ƒ (n,r)
sendPromise: ƒ (n,r)
subscribe: ƒ a(e)
supports: ƒ (e)
unsubscribe: ƒ (e)
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Вы этот вывод внутри ф-ии `Br` сделали?

Comment: Ой, Боже, что-то я затупил. Скорее всего проблема в том, что это асинхронная ф-ия и вам надо в консоль выводить не `bridge.send`, а его результат, т.е. вам надо написать `bridge.send(...).then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: у меня в одном файле две функции, одна экспортируется через `export default`, другая `(Br)` через `export {Br};`
Когда я сделала в `Br` то не получилось вывести. Наверное экспорт кривой. Сделала в основную и тогда получилось вывести эту структуру.

Сделала в основную функцию `console.log(bridge.send("VKWebAppGetClientVersion"))`
и в консоли :
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object

но по сути должен вывестись номер, а я не очень понимаю что с этим делать

Comment: спасибо, попробую так

Comment: Ну всё, раз промис показал, значит я точно прав :)

Answer (score 0):

Решение :

```
bridge.send("VKWebAppGetClientVersion").then(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: Это решило вашу проблему?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]